# postgres - unique constraint with multi-column and null

Tags: postgresql, psql

What is the best way to solve this problem. I have defined following table test:

```
  Column    |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | integer           |           | not null | 
 name        | character varying |           | not null | 
 description | character varying |           |          | 
 a_id        | character varying |           | not null | 
 b_id        | character varying |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "test_ukey" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name, a_id, b_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "test_a_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES testa(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Please note that 'id' and 'name' cannot be NULL while b_id can be NULL which has special meaning for the business logic. This can also be set to some default value in case dealing with NULL is an issue. As per unique constraint, I want to allow only one entry for same (name, a_id, b_id). However, I want to allow/disallow following inserts:

```
   id       name        a_id        b_id
    1       admin       a_1               --> allowed (only one entry if there is no existing same row as b_id not null)
    2       admin       a_1               --> not allowed since row 1 already exist (admin, a_1, null)
    3       admin       a_1         b_1   --> not allowed since row 1 already exist (admin, a_1, null)
    4       operator    a_1         b_1   --> allowed
    5       operator    a_1         b_2   --> allowed
    6       operator    a_1               --> not allowed since row 4 or 5 already exists
    7       operator    a_2               --> allowed (only one entry if there is no existing same row as b_id not null)
```

Is it possible to achieve this by creating/modifying unique constraints or index?
I know this can be achieved using triggers which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

That is an unusual requirement, since NULL conflicts with everything. One possible solution is to use an infinite range instead of NULL and an exclusion constraint:

```
-- to create a GiST index on "text" columns
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

-- so that we can have a range for "all strings"
CREATE TYPE textrange AS RANGE (SUBTYPE = text);

ALTER TABLE test ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   name WITH =,
   a_id WITH =,
   textrange(b_id, b_id, '[]') WITH &&
);
```

For details about this technique, see [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/unique-constraint-null-conflicts-with-everything/). Custom range types are described in the [`CREATE TYPE` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html#SQL-CREATETYPE-RANGE).